# Proof for the distance between a point and a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$N$ is a non-zero vector, $c$ a number, and $Q$ a point. $P_0$ is the point
of intersection of the line passing through $Q$, in the direction of $N$, and the plane $X\cdot{N} = c$. Show that for all points $P$ of the plane, 
$$\lVert Q - P_0 \rVert < \lVert Q - P \rVert$$

This seems obvious since the line is in the direction of a vector that's normal to the plane, but how can I prove it?

$$P_0 = Q + tN$$
$$Q-P_0 = -tN$$
$$\lVert Q-P_0 \rVert = t\sqrt{N\cdot{N}}$$

$$X\cdot{N} = N\cdot{P} = c$$
$$Q-P = P_0-tN - P = P_0 - tN - \frac{c}{N}$$

But these don't seem to help.

Comment: Hint: If you draw the triangle between $Q$, $P_0$, and $P$, you'll have a *right* triangle.  Then, use the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I understand now, thank you!